# Div with multiple color overlays on hover

Tags: html, css, image, hover

I want to create a hover effect on an image that when hovered over multiple colored divs appear. I figure I can do this with CSS, but am having trouble getting the result I want.

What I am aiming for it to look like in the end: 
[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="row thumbrow">
<ul class="small-block-grid-2 medium-block-grid-2 large-block-grid-4 thumbgrid">
    <li>
        <div class="thumb">
                {{ cms:page_file:thumb_one.image:image}}
                <span class="center">{{ cms:page:thumb_one.text:string }}</span>
            <div class="yellow">                    
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.thumb {
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
    height: 170px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.thumb:after {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.8); 
    content:'';
    display: block;
    height: 170px;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}

.thumb:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
    padding: 20px;
    transition: opacity .4s;
}

.thumb:hover .yellow {
    content:'';
    display: block;
    height: 170px;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 5;
    background: #f9d33a;
}  

span.center {
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    top: -100px;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Eric - for the `.yellow` class - the css would be `position:absolute: left:5px; top:5p;right:5px;bottom:5px` - (or similar values to taste). It's the `position:absolute` you are missing. Same for the `.center` css class. To stack them add css `zindex:1` , `z-index:2`.

Comment: Ah, many thanks. If you put that into an answer I will accept it as correct :)

Comment: Great stuff. Added that. All the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As comments, the essential part was the missing of css `position:absolute` for the elements `.yellow` and `.center`

I have run up a demo **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/KgYVs/1/)**

The use of the selectors `:after`  are not necessary , in the demo the CSS has been shortened to :

```
.thumb {
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
    height: 170px; width:100%;
    overflow: hidden; 
}
.thumb .yellow, .thumb .center { display:none; }
.thumb:hover .yellow {
    content:'.'; display: block;
    position: absolute; z-index: 1;
    bottom:10px; left: 10px; right:10px; top: 10px;
    background: #f9d33a; opacity: 0.5;
}  
.thumb:hover .center {
    display:block; color: white;
    position: absolute; z-index: 2;
    top: 20px; left: 20px; right: 20px; bottom:20px;
}
```

---

Some values ( like the top, bottom, left, right offsets I made up ), the key part is the `position:absolute`

Answer (score 0):

You can use hover selectors along with sibling selectors to display on hover, similar to the suckerfish menu:

http://jsbin.com/qerucawe/3

http://jsbin.com/qerucawe/3/edit